# Url rewrite for website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing, iis-8

I have a running website for which I have a required to change Url scheme. What we want is to two-fold:

1) Remove all controller names from the urls, so

```
http://foo.com/controller/bar --> http://foo.com/bar
```

2) Redirect english language url to language specific urls (english to swedish), so

```
http://foo.com/controller/About -->http://foo.com/om-oss
```

We have around 7-10 standard pages which I am thinking can be done using page specific url rewrites (301) by mapping old to new url structure. A sample would be good enough for me to follow.

Secondly, we also have certain dynamic/custom urls which should also be converted to language specific url for better SEO like

```
http://foo.com/controller/17-my-article --> http://foo.com/17-min-artikel
```

Now, these I can again write specific urls as language translation won't be easy. Although while fetching data I only rely on ID, so the custom urls can stay as they currently are with the exception fo removing controller name (Point 1).

Can you suggest the url rewrite regex to handle 301 redirect in web.config which can take care of this requirement?

Comment: Have you tried ARR?

Comment: Isn't that meant for load balancing and reverse proxy. I have only relatively simple application hosted on a single web server with only 7-10 fixed pages and some 20-30 odd dynamic/custom urls.